# Call Android numeric keyboard in Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, android-keypad

I'm trying to program a small UI using Google Script and want to have the input method be the numeric keyboard when I pull the site up on my phone. I cannot find anything online which addresses this, is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using UiApp or HTMLService?

Comment: Then I'm afraid you can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the input type from `text` to `number`, like this:

```
<input type="number" value="0" />
```